# loading csv file to mysql with VB.net File not Found

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to load a .csv file into my MySQL database via VB.net. The .csv file is in the same folder on the server as this script.

here's my script:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Data.Odbc" %>


<%           
    Dim connectionstring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBstring").ConnectionString

    Dim connectme As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(connectionstring)

    Dim ODBCdataset As DataSet = New DataSet()

    Dim sqlquery As String = "load data infile '1.csv' into table ttest fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '""' lines terminated by '\r\n' (field1, field2, field3, field4)"

    connectme.Open()
    Dim ODBCdataadapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(sqlquery, connectme)
    ODBCdataadapter.Fill(ODBCdataset, "ttest")
    connectme.Close()
    Response.Redirect("index.html")
%>
```

and here's my error message

```
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.73-community]File 'test.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do to fix it? Thanks

EDIT: I've changed the name of my file to 1.csv in case I mis-spelled it, and i'm still having the same error message.

Comment: It needs to be in the data directory or you need to give the full path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load data local infile ERROR 2 file not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623984/load-data-local-infile-error-2-file-not-found)

Comment: hi, how do I give the full path?